# the command find not working with -name option in sh file

Tags: shell-script, shell, find, basename

I am using the following command to retrieve the number of files which names contains `sv` or `json` in a given directory in a remote server:

```
nbs_files=`ssh -q -i ${sshkey} ${user}@${server} "find ${path}/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*sv*' -o -name '*.json' -exec basename {} \; | wc -l"`
```

This command returns only the number of `.json` files, whereas files with `sv` in their names exist in the `${path}`.

When I remove the `-o -name '*.json'` part, the command works well, and returns the number of files containing the 'sv' in their names.

Does anyone know how can I modify the command in order to retrieve the files containing `sv` in their names and the files with the extension `.json` as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is and/or operator precedence in the `find` expression. Specifically, the implicit AND between adjacent tests has higher precedence than the OR (`-o`) between the two name tests. So the test expression gets parsed as:

```
    -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*sv*'
OR
    -name '*.json' -exec basename {} \;
```

...and since the `-name '*.json'` is the only one that's part of the same branch as `-exec`, the `-exec` only runs for json files.

The solution is to override the normal precedence with explicit parentheses around the `-name` tests:

```
nbs_files=$(ssh -q -i ${sshkey} ${user}@${server} "find ${path}/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f '(' -name '*sv*' -o -name '*.json' ')' -exec basename {} \; | wc -l")
```

BTW, I also took the liberty of replacing the backticks with `$( )` -- they're the more modern option, are easier to read, and don't have the same weird escaping anomalies that backticks have. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/what-is-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming) and [BashFAQ #82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: Of course one has to wonder what directory names the OP had to warrant running basename before counting the results. If there are no embedded newlines then removing the `-exec basename {} \;` will give the same results but without the cost of running a process per matching file. If the OP is using gnu find - likely given the `linux` tag, then `nbs_files=$(ssh -q -i ${sshkey} ${user}@${server} "find ${path}/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f '(' -name '*sv*' -o -name '*.json' ')' -printf '%f\n' | wc -l")` will avoid the process per matching file even with embedded newlines in the directory names.

Comment: @icarus, though filenames with newlines will affect the count. You don't really need to print the actual filenames if all you're going to do is pipe to `wc`. Just something like `find ... -printf '\n' | wc -l` would do

Comment: @ilkkachu The point is that to reproduce the behavior you do need to print the filenames, you can't just print a newline for each file. Note I am not saying that the behavior is the desired one, I strongly suspect it is not, but your solution answers a different problem.

Comment: @icarus, well, they did say "retrieve the number of files", so I thought they wouldn't want names with newlines to count as two. Or was there something else I missed?